# D3 - Area graph with logarithmic scale

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, graph

I'm trying to make area graph with Y axis in a log scale. Below I reproduced my error using some example code I've found online (my code is a bit different but essentially works the same).

---

I started with basic graph:
[image]

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
    width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Read the data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/data_to_viz/master/Example_dataset/3_TwoNumOrdered_comma.csv",

  // When reading the csv, I must format variables:
  function(d){
    return { date : d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.date), value : d.value }
  },

  // Now I can use this dataset:
  function(data) {

    // Add X axis --> it is a date format
    var x = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }))
      .range([ 0, width ]);
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // Add Y axis
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([1, d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.value; })])
      .range([ height, 0 ]);
    svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // Add the line
    svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date) })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.value) })
        )

})
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

---

Then I tried to change it to an area graph with log scale. Each feature separately works fine - but combined they are breaking the graph:
[image]

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
    width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Read the data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/data_to_viz/master/Example_dataset/3_TwoNumOrdered_comma.csv",

  // When reading the csv, I must format variables:
  function(d){
    return { date : d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.date), value : d.value }
  },

  // Now I can use this dataset:
  function(data) {

    // Add X axis --> it is a date format
    var x = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }))
      .range([ 0, width ]);
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // Add Y axis
    var y = d3.scaleLog()
      .domain([1, d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.value; })])
      .range([ height, 0 ]);
    svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // Add the line
    svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", d3.area()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date) })
        .y0(y(0))
        .y1(function(d) { return y(d.value) })
        )

})
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

---

The only thing I've changed is:

```js
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
// into
var y = d3.scaleLog()
```

and

```js
svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("d", d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date) })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.value) })
    )
// into
svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("fill", "steelblue")
    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("d", d3.area()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date) })
        .y0(y(0))
        .y1(function(d) { return y(d.value) })
    )
```

I don't understand what is wrong.

Every other type of scale (`linear`, `sqrt`, `pow`) works just fine when combined with area graph. Only problem is with `log` scale. And it is literally the only difference. You can change `scaleLog` into `scaleSqrt` and it just works...

And I would like to note here that my scale does not start at 0 (`log(0)` is negative infinity). So that is not the problem.

Comment: What [Andrew said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70085448/5768908) or, if you were using newer D3 versions, you could keep your `y(0)` by using a Symlog scale: `var y = d3.scaleSymlog().etc...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is how you set the baseline (y0):

```
.attr("d", d3.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date) })
    .y0(y(0))
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.value) })
)
```

Here you are using 0 with the log scale (`y(0)`), which of course will return undefined. This is why other scales don't give you trouble but the log scale does. You could provide a value very close to zero to the y scale, but you know where the baseline should be: it should be equal to the first value in the y scale's range, there is no need to use the scale to determine this:

```
  .y0(height)
```

As seen below:

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
    width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Read the data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/data_to_viz/master/Example_dataset/3_TwoNumOrdered_comma.csv",

  // When reading the csv, I must format variables:
  function(d){
    return { date : d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.date), value : d.value }
  },

  // Now I can use this dataset:
  function(data) {

    // Add X axis --> it is a date format
    var x = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }))
      .range([ 0, width ]);
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // Add Y axis
    var y = d3.scaleLog()
      .domain([1, d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.value; })])
      .range([ height, 0 ]);
    svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // Add the line
    svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", d3.area()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date) })
        .y0(height)
        .y1(function(d) { return y(d.value) })
        )

})
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Is there any reason to use scale to set baseline (y0) in this type of graph? Or `height` will suffice in all cases? I've seen many tutorials use it like this and I wonder why.

Comment: Using the range value that represents the bottom of the chart will work fine for setting y0, if you want the bottom of the area to occupy that space. If you end up tinkering with the range afterwards, you'll need to remember to update y0, but you can also use `scale.range()[0]` to access the first value of the range. No real reason to use the scale unless you want the baseline to be scaled to a value that isn't the top or bottom of the chart.